# Can't initialize a struct using an initializer list if it inherits?

Tags: c++, inheritance, struct, aggregate-initialization

I'm puzzled by this fragment of (C++14) code I wrote:

```
struct B {};
struct C     { int m; };
struct D : B { int m; };

int main() {
    C c = { 1 }; // this works
    D d = { 1 }; // this doesn't work
}
```

I'm fine writing a constructor for `D` myself, but I can't find a good explanation for *why* the struct `D` is no longer initializable with an initializer list. All I changed was make it inherit from a completely empty class -- I suppose I somehow made it behave less struct-like.

How exactly does my compiler handle the structs `C` and `D` differently?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It works for `C` because it is an [aggregate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4178175/1708801) and therefore it is using [aggregate initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) but `D` is not an aggregate because it has a base class. The obvious work-around as you mention is to write a constructor.

This is covered in the draft C++ standard section `8.5.1` Aggregates *[dcl.init.aggr]* with emphasis mine:

> An aggregate is an array or a class (Clause 9) with no user-provided constructors (12.1), no private or
>   protected non-static data members (Clause 11), **no base classes (Clause 10)**, and no virtual functions (10.3).

There is a proposal: [Extension to aggregate initialization](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0017r1.html) to remove that restriction. As chris points out this was accepted by Evolution Working Group but as far as I understand now needs to accepted by Core as well.

Comment: According to [this trip report](https://botondballo.wordpress.com/2015/11/09/trip-report-c-standards-meeting-in-kona-october-2015/), the proposal was accepted at Kona.

Comment: @chris I did not see the changes applied to the latest draft so I was not sure, although I thought I remembered reading that it was accepted from that trip report.

Comment: @chris ok, now I get it. It was accepted by EWG, so as I understand it. It now has to go to CWG before it can be applied to the draft standard.

Answer (score 3):

`D` is no longer an aggregate type so it cannot be directly initialized with an initialization list.  If you provide a constructor then it will work.

```
struct B {};
struct C     { int m; };
struct D : B { int m; D(int m_) : m(m_) {} };

int main() 
{
    C c = { 1 }; // this works
    D d = { 1 }; // this works
}
```

<kbd>[Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0b4964b798e1e4e7)</kbd>

Answer (score -1):

struct c is a POD while struct D is an object.  Class initializer rules apply because of the inheritance.

Comment: `C` is also and object.